# Unable to add security token for identity WCF with java client using weblogic

Tags: java, web-services, wcf

I faced an error while i'm trying to connect to WCF webservice using java project hosted on weblogic application server 10.3.0.0

i deploy my WAR to the weblogic fine and when the java client invoke the WCF webservice, i got the following exception , Note : the same project is working fine when it hosted on GlassFish :-

```
javax.xml.rpc.JAXRPCException: weblogic.xml.crypto.wss.WSSecurityException: Unable to add security token for identity
connect.exceptions.BackEndExecutionException: javax.xml.rpc.JAXRPCException: weblogic.xml.crypto.wss.WSSecurityException: Unable to add security token for identity
  at connect.backend.ws.tw.TradeWindSec.execute(TradeWindSec.java:129)
  at connect.engine.Processor.process(Processor.java:158)
  at connect.ejb.ConnectBean.adaptorService(ConnectBean.java:61)
  at connect.ejb.Connect_ev8oqy_EOImpl.adaptorService(Connect_ev8oqy_EOImpl.java:61)
  at connect.ws.ConnectWebservice.adaptorService(ConnectWebservice.java:31)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
  at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.invokeMethod(RPCProvider.java:397)
  at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:186)
  at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
  at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
  at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
  at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
  at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
  at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
  at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
  at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:292)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:42)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:42)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3496)
  at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
  at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(Unknown Source)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2180)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2086)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1406)
  at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
  at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
```

my java code for this webservice client as following:-

```
    package connect.backend.ws.tw;


//import com.sun.xml.ws.fault.ServerSOAPFaultException;
import connect.engine.Call;
import connect.engine.Message;
import connect.exceptions.BackEndExecutionException;
import connect.util.ConnectConstants;
import java.net.URL;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider;


public class TradeWindSec extends TradeWind {


    private static org.tempuri.TradewindService tradeWindWebservicesec = null;
    private static org.tempuri.ITradewindService tradeWindWebserviceBindingsec = null;


    public TradeWindSec() throws Exception {
        if (tradeWindWebserviceBindingsec == null) {
            tradeWindWebservicesec = new org.tempuri.TradewindService(new URL(ConnectConstants.getProperty(ConnectConstants.TradeWindWSDL)));
            tradeWindWebserviceBindingsec = tradeWindWebservicesec.getWSHttpBindingITradewindService();
            ((BindingProvider) tradeWindWebserviceBindingsec).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, ConnectConstants.getProperty(ConnectConstants.TWWebServiceUser));
            ((BindingProvider) tradeWindWebserviceBindingsec).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, ConnectConstants.getProperty(ConnectConstants.TWWebServicePass));
        }
    }


    private String callTradeWindMethod(Call call) throws NumberFormatException,
            RemoteException,
            BackEndExecutionException {
        String tradeWindResult = null;
        String methodName = call.getParameter(Call.SERVICE_METHOD).toString().trim();
        if (methodName.equals("Inquiry")) {
            tradeWindResult = tradeWindWebserviceBindingsec.inquiry(
                    call.getParameter(Call.SERVICE_ID).toString(),
                    Float.parseFloat(call.getParameter(Call.VERSION).toString()),
                    Integer.parseInt(call.getParameter(Call.CONSUMER).toString()),
                    call.getParameter(Call.DB_USERNAME).toString(),
                    call.getParameter(Call.DB_PASSWORD).toString(),
                    call.getParameter(Call.PARAMETER_LIST).toString(),
                    call.getParameter(Call.RQ_UID1).toString());
        } else if (methodName.equals("Post")) {
            tradeWindResult = tradeWindWebserviceBindingsec.post(
                    call.getParameter(Call.SERVICE_ID).toString(),
                    Float.parseFloat(call.getParameter(Call.VERSION).toString()),
                    Integer.parseInt(call.getParameter(Call.CONSUMER).toString()),
                    call.getParameter(Call.DB_USERNAME).toString(),
                    call.getParameter(Call.DB_PASSWORD).toString(),
                    call.getParameter(Call.PARAMETER_LIST).toString(),
                    call.getParameter(Call.RQ_UID1).toString());
        } else if (methodName.equals("Swift")) {
            tradeWindResult = tradeWindWebserviceBindingsec.swift(
                    call.getParameter(Call.SERVICE_ID).toString(),
                    Float.parseFloat(call.getParameter(Call.VERSION).toString()),
                    Integer.parseInt(call.getParameter(Call.CONSUMER).toString()),
                    call.getParameter(Call.DB_USERNAME).toString(),
                    call.getParameter(Call.DB_PASSWORD).toString(),
                    call.getParameter(Call.PARAMETER_LIST).toString(),
                    call.getParameter(Call.RQ_UID1).toString());
        } else if (methodName.equals("Advice")) {
            tradeWindResult = tradeWindWebserviceBindingsec.advise(
                    call.getParameter(Call.SERVICE_ID).toString(),
                    Float.parseFloat(call.getParameter(Call.VERSION).toString()),
                    Integer.parseInt(call.getParameter(Call.CONSUMER).toString()),
                    call.getParameter(Call.DB_USERNAME).toString(),
                    call.getParameter(Call.DB_PASSWORD).toString(),
                    call.getParameter(Call.PARAMETER_LIST).toString(),
                    call.getParameter(Call.RQ_UID1).toString());
            if (tradeWindResult == null) {
                throw new BackEndExecutionException("Unexcpected result from Ethix-Trade, result is null");
            }
            tradeWindResult = tradeWindResult.replaceFirst("<Advice>", "<Inquiry>").trim();
            /**
             * tradeWindResult = tradeWindResult.substring(0, tradeWindResult.lastIndexOf("</Report>"))+ "</Inquiry>"; OR the following code
             */
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(tradeWindResult);
            builder.delete(tradeWindResult.lastIndexOf("</Advice>"), tradeWindResult.length());
            builder.append("</Inquiry>");
            tradeWindResult = builder.toString();
        } else if (methodName.equals("Report")) {
            tradeWindResult = tradeWindWebserviceBindingsec.report(
                    call.getParameter(Call.SERVICE_ID).toString(),
                    Float.parseFloat(call.getParameter(Call.VERSION).toString()),
                    Integer.parseInt(call.getParameter(Call.CONSUMER).toString()),
                    call.getParameter(Call.DB_USERNAME).toString(),
                    call.getParameter(Call.DB_PASSWORD).toString(),
                    call.getParameter(Call.PARAMETER_LIST).toString(),
                    call.getParameter(Call.RQ_UID1).toString());
            if (tradeWindResult == null) {
                throw new BackEndExecutionException("Unexcpected result from Ethix-Trade, result is null");
            }
            tradeWindResult = tradeWindResult.replaceFirst("<Report>", "<Inquiry>").trim();
            /**
             * tradeWindResult = tradeWindResult.substring(0, tradeWindResult.lastIndexOf("</Report>"))+ "</Inquiry>"; OR the following code
             */
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(tradeWindResult);
            builder.delete(tradeWindResult.lastIndexOf("</Report>"), tradeWindResult.length());
            builder.append("</Inquiry>");
            tradeWindResult = builder.toString();
        }
        if (tradeWindResult == null) {
            throw new BackEndExecutionException("Unexcpected result from Ethix-Trade, result is null");
        }
        return tradeWindResult;
    }


    @Override
    public Object execute(Message message) throws BackEndExecutionException {
        String result = null;
        Call call = message.getCall();
        try {
            result = callTradeWindMethod(call);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new BackEndExecutionException(
                    "Service version or consumer might be wrong: "
                    + e.getMessage());
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            tradeWindWebserviceBindingsec = null;
            throw new BackEndExecutionException(
                    "Failed to contact Ethix-Trade webservice: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            tradeWindWebserviceBindingsec = null;
            throw new BackEndExecutionException(e.getMessage());
        }
        return result;
    }


    public static void reconnect() {
       tradeWindWebserviceBindingsec = null;
    }
}
```

Kindly help me with this error and how i can resolve it.